# Error authenticating an API requester with kerberos library on a NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, express, kerberos

I installed NodeJS 18.18 on a windows 10 machine. During installation I checked the box to automatically install the necessary tools (Python, Visual Studio build tools...). Then I installed kerberos library version 2.0.3 which according to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kerberos/v/2.0.3) is available to windows.

As a previous conditions to install kerberos library, the reader is advised to install windows-build-tools by running npm install -g windows-build-tools. However, any attempt to install these tools is replied with error message "Node.js now includes build tools for Windows."
Once I have everything installed, I keep receiving error

> Error: `**initializeServer**` is not implemented yet for windows
> at Object.initializeServer (C:...\Bootstrap\react-node-app\node_modules\kerberos\lib\util.js:80:8)
> (...)

on any attempt on server side to process SPNEGO token received from requester. Below I show code used.
I am a newbie in NodeJS and I would appreciate any help on installing kerberos library or any proposal to perform server-side API requester authentication via kerberos.
Thank you in advance, Paulo Sardinha

I developed a simple NodeJS Expresss server:

My code on server-side is very simple:

```
const express = require('express');
const kerberos = require('kerberos');
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);`

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authorizationHeader || !authorizationHeader.startsWith('Negotiate ')) {
    res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Negotiate');
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  const token = authorizationHeader.replace('Negotiate ', '');

  // Initialize the Kerberos server
  kerberos.initializeServer('HTTP/my-url@MY-DOMAIN', (err, server) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error initializing server:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }
    // Authenticate the client's token
    server.step(token, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Kerberos authentication failed:', err);
        res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Negotiate');
        res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
      }
      // Authentication successful
      const authenticatedUser = server.username;
      res.status(200).send(`Authenticated as: ${authenticatedUser}`);
    });

  });
  
});

const port = 3001;
httpServer.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I was expecting the server to validate the client.
I did a wireshark trace and I can confirm this error occurs on server-side after the server replies to client with HTTP 401 status and HTTP header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate and the latter resubmits request with Authorization token containing a kerberos ticket.